# Specify mapping expression for complextype

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to map an XElement to an Item entity using AutoMapper. 
The item has two properties with the same complex type. Those properties should be mapped from different attributes.

```
class Identity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public  int Name { get; set; }
}

class Item
{
    public Identity Identity { get; set; }
    public Identity Identity2 { get; set; }
}

class ItemProfile : Profile
{
    public ItemProfile()
    {
        var IdentityMapping = CreateMap<XElement, Identity>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ID, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Attribute("id").Value))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Attribute("name").Value));

        var Identity2Mapping = CreateMap<XElement, Identity>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ID, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Attribute("item_id").Value))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Attribute("item_name").Value));            

        CreateMap<XElement, Item>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Identity, /*How to use IdentityMapping?*/)
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Identity2, /*How to use Identity2Mapping?*/);
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class ItemTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void SouldMapItem()
    {
        IMapper mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile(new ItemProfile())).CreateMapper();
        var doc = XElement.Parse(@"<item id='1' name='one' item_id='10' item_name='ten'></item>");
        var item = mapper.Map<Item>(doc);
        Assert.IsNotNull(item);            
    }
}
```

How can I specify an mapping for each Identity property in the ItemProfile?